# How to match first characters with a powershell script

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-negation

I am trying to move files to a certain folder if they start with a letter and delete them if they start with anything other than a letter.

My code:

```
Function moveOrDelete($source, $dest)
{
    $aToZ = '^[a-zA-Z].*'
    $notALetter = '^[^a-zA-Z].*'

    Get-ChildItem -Path $source\$aToZ -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination $dest

    Get-ChildItem -Path $source\$notALetter -Recurse | Remove-Item
}
```

As I understand it the caret will match on the first character when it's outside of the brackets. In other words, the regex in the `$aToZ` variable will match anything that begins with a letter. the `.*` part will allow the rest of the file name to be anything. The caret inside the brackets negates the statement so if the file name begins with anything other than a letter it will match. I can't get it to work and I'm not getting any errors which leads me to believe that my regex is wrong.

I have checked this with online tools including this one: https://regex101.com/ and they check out.

I have also used variations of the regex like `^[a-zA-Z]` that don't work. Some patterns like `[a-zA-Z]*` move the files but it's not the pattern that I want.

Here is how I'm calling the funcion:

```
moveOrDelete ".\source" ".\dest"
```

And here are the sample file names I'm using:

```
a.txt
z.txt
1.txt
.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Path` argument doesn't understand regular expressions, it takes a string and can perform wildcarding but not complex string processing.

So, you need to check the name of each file against the regex with the `-match` operator. The following should help:

```
Function moveOrDelete($source, $dest)
{
    $aToZ = '^[a-zA-Z].*'
    $notALetter = '^[^a-zA-Z].*'
    Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.name -match $aToZ } | Move-Item -Destination $dest
    Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.name -match $notALetter } | Remove-Item
}
```

Here, you need to filter the file names with the `Where-Object` cmdlet, then pipe to the move or remove.

Comment: Your `ForEach-Object` is unnecessary: you can pipe directly to `Remove-Item`.  The same applies to `Move-Item`.

Comment: THANKS!! This fixed it. I ended up piping it like TheIncorribible recommended.